# DataGrid ColumnHeader PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown event restrictions

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

I have datagrid column header like this:

```
<datagridtemplatecolumn.headertemplate>
    <datatemplate previewmouseleftbuttondown="TextBlock_DocumentsClick">
        <stackpanel orientation="Vertical">
            <textblock text="Doctor Name" previewmouseleftbuttondown="TextBlock_ReceptionsClick" name="DoctorName" />
            <textbox name="SearchReceptionDoctor" width="120" tag="DoctorName" text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.RecDoctorNameFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <textbox.inputbindings>
                    <keybinding key="Enter" command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.FilterReceptionsCommand}" commandparameter="{Binding Tag, ElementName=SearchReceptionDoctor}" />
                </textbox.inputbindings>
            </textbox>
        </stackpanel>
    </datatemplate>
</datagridtemplatecolumn.headertemplate>
```

Now it works good, only problem is that I want to restrict event to fire when I click on a textbox. Is there a way to check if I have clicked on a textbox and prevent functionality of my event to be fired? This is how my event looks in code behind:

```
private void TextBlock_BookingsClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        (this.DataContext as PatientViewModel).ColumnName = (sender as TextBlock).Name.ToString();
        (this.DataContext as PatientViewModel).PatientTabBookingsSorting();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PanLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, String.Format("Bookings tab datagrid text block click event failed! \nReason: {0} \nStackTrace: {1} \nInnerException", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try OriginalSource property of MouseButtonEventArgs this will give you the exact control on which event occur

Answer (score 0):

I would get the type of the sender and check if this is a Textbox

Comment: But the sender will always be DataGridColumn or I'm wrong?

Comment: mmm now I'm confused, where is the TextBlock_BookingsClick defined on the XAML?